# Where can I buy Guatemalan quetzales (GTQ) in Benito Juárez Airport (Mexico City)?

Tags: money, mexico, mexico-city, mex

There are countless money exchange booths in the Mexico City airport, but I can't find one that exchanges Guatemalan quetzales (specifically that sells them).  Is there one somewhere?

Comment: Every time I've been in the area you could only exchange pesos and quetzales at the border and border towns. I never found any banks that accepted the currency of the other country as exchange. In Xela (Quetzaltenango) after much searching I found exchange bureaus near a local market that would exchange pesos. Generally I had the impression that Mexico doesn't even like to acknowledge that Central America exists. Within Central America people are only interested in USD. You may be able to find travellers going in the opposite direction or people arriving on flights from Guate...

Comment: I was able to buy quetzales at the Guatemala airport (GUA) upon arrival, but I always prefer to arrive with some local currency, to tip a baggage carrier, for instance, if the need should arise before I can exchange currency.

Comment: Oh I've never been to an airport in CA so I didn't think of that. Could you buy with pesos or only with USD?

Comment: @hippietrail: I was able to buy with pesos. I don't think I could buy pesos there, though... their sign only mentioned USD and Euros.

Answer (score 2):

This is of course a question which is probably answerable best by experience, but since I think something is always better than nothing, here's a [list of all the currency exchanges (In Spanish)](http://cambiopesodolar.com.mx/casas-de-cambio-en-el-aeropuerto-de-la-ciudad-de-mexico/) on Benito Juarez Airport.

There is also an **[interactive map](http://www.aicm.com.mx/en/interactive-map)** on the airport website which shows a list of banks and currency exchanges. They are mostly nearby, so I believe with a little bit of hunting, you might be able to find some GTQ.

Several articles also mention that the airport is probably the best place to find currency exchange at decent prices all across the city. One [such article](http://mexdfmagazine.com/2013/05/02/the-secret-to-money-exchange-in-mexico-city/) which claims that you should be able to find GTQ at one of the exchanges I listed earlier.